# Bad day count with `scales::label_time`

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a table that looks like this one to track the temperature over time (`d_raw`).
I was thinking of using `lubridate` to tidy my data and then plot it.
I have a problem with the X axis which does not respect the count from zero (and start at 1).

I have found a way around it with `labels =  function(x) {paste(hms(x)/days(1))}` but it is not very graceful.

What do you have to suggest to improve my script?
Thanks in advance

```r
library(tidyverse)

d_raw <- tibble(
  Time = c("2023-02-01 14:00", "2023-02-02 12:00", "2023-02-03 13:00", "2023-02-04 14:00", "2023-02-05 15:00"),
  Temperature = c(25,18,20,19,32)
)

Tzero <- ymd_hm("2023-02-01 8:00")

d <- d_raw |> 
  mutate(Time = ymd_hm(Time),
         spent = interval(Tzero, Time))

d
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   Time                Temperature spent                                           
#>   <dttm>                    <dbl> <Interval>                                      
#> 1 2023-02-01 14:00:00          25 2023-02-01 08:00:00 UTC--2023-02-01 14:00:00 UTC
#> 2 2023-02-02 12:00:00          18 2023-02-01 08:00:00 UTC--2023-02-02 12:00:00 UTC
#> 3 2023-02-03 13:00:00          20 2023-02-01 08:00:00 UTC--2023-02-03 13:00:00 UTC
#> 4 2023-02-04 14:00:00          19 2023-02-01 08:00:00 UTC--2023-02-04 14:00:00 UTC
#> 5 2023-02-05 15:00:00          32 2023-02-01 08:00:00 UTC--2023-02-05 15:00:00 UTC

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = spent, y = Temperature)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Time spent (d)") +
  ylim(c(0, NA))

p + scale_x_time(limits = c(0,NA),
               breaks = scales::breaks_width("2 days"),
               labels = scales::label_time("%d"))
```

[image]

```r
p + scale_x_time(limits = c(0,NA),
                 breaks = scales::breaks_width("2 days"),
                 labels =  function(x) {paste(hms(x)/days(1))})
#> Warning in .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet): Some strings failed
#> to parse, or all strings are NAs
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Sorry for this typo. 
Start at 0 like you do, but I was hoping to do it in scale_* and not updating the tibble.
Thank's

Comment: It seems like your 2nd plot already does that, how do you want it to be different?

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it simpler to convert special data types like time intervals into plain numbers upstream of ggplot.

```
d <- d_raw |> 
  mutate(Time = ymd_hm(Time),
         spent = interval(Tzero, Time),
         day_num = as.numeric(spent/days(1)))

ggplot(d, aes(x = day_num, y = Temperature)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Time spent (d)") +
  ylim(c(0, NA)) +
  xlim(c(0, NA))
```

[image]